# Parallelize output using OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I've written a C++ app that has to process a lot of data. Using OpenMP I parallelized the processing phase quite well and, embarrassingly, found that the output writing is now the bottleneck. I decided to use a `parallel for` there as well, as the order in which I output items is irrelevant; they just need to be output as coherent chunks.

Below is a simplified version of the output code, showing all the variables except for two custom iterators in the "collect data in related" loop. My question is: is this the correct and optimal way to solve this problem? I read about the `barrier` pragma, do I need that?

```
long i, n = nrows();

#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    std::vector<MyData> related;
    for (size_t j=0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
        related.push_back(data[i][j]);
    sort(related.rbegin(), related.rend());

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        std::cout << data[i].label << "\n";
        for (size_t j=0; j<related.size(); j++)
            std::cout << "    " << related[j].label << "\n";
    }
}
```

(I labeled this question `c` as I imagine OpenMP is very similar in C and C++. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to get around output contention is to write the thread-local output to a string stream, (can be done in parallel) and then push the contents to `cout` (requires synchronization).

Something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    std::vector<MyData> related;
    for (size_t j=0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
        related.push_back(data[i][j]);
    sort(related.rbegin(), related.rend());

    std::stringstream buf;
    buf << data[i].label << "\n";
    for (size_t j=0; j<related.size(); j++)
        buf << "    " << related[j].label << "\n";

    #pragma omp critical
    std::cout << buf.rdbuf();
}
```

This offers much more fine-grained locking and the performance should increase accordingly. On the other hand, this *still* uses locking. So another way would be to use an array of stream buffers, one for each thread, and pushing them to `cout` sequentially *after* the parallel loop. This has the advantage of avoiding costly locks, and the output to `cout` must be serialized anyway.

On the other hand, you can even try to omit the `critical` section in the above code. In my experience, this works since the underlying streams have their own way of controlling concurrency. But I believe that this behaviour is strictly implementation defined and not portable.

Answer (score 2):

`cout` contention is still going to be a problem here.  Why not output the results in some thread-local storage and collate them to the desired location centrally, meaning no contention.  For example, you could have each target thread for the parallel code write to a separate filestream or memory stream and just concatenate them afterwards, since ordering is not important.  Or postprocess the results from multiple places instead of one - no contention, single write only required.

Comment: yes, access to the `FILE` structure underlying `cout` should be implicitly mutexed with `flockfile`, `omp parallel for` will gain nothing, here.

Comment: @larsmans - good luck - in general `omp critical` is a yellow flag for perf, and in this case since it's I/O logic, doubly so.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, the parallel for is there because of the sorting phase, which I imagined would take lots of CPU time (and have replaced with a `partial_sort_copy`).