# Using std::cout in a parallel for loop using OpenMP

Tags: c++, printing, openmp

I want to parallelize a for-loop in C++ using OpenMP. In that loop I want to print some results:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    if (test.successful() == true) {
        std::cout << test.id() << " " << test.result() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The result I get without using OpenMP:

```
3 23923.23
1 32329.32
2 23239.45
```

However I get the following using a parallel for-loop:

```
314924.4244.5
434.
4343.43123
```

How can I avoid such an output?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the printing is not defined as an atomic operation, thus context switch occurs while printing to the standard output is still ongoing.

Solution: You must make the for loop body an atomic operation, using  `#pragma omp atomic`

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    if (test.successful() == true) {
        #pragma omp atomic
        std::cout << test.id() << " " << test.result() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `atomic` mean?

Comment: I get the following error: `error: invalid operator for ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘<<’ token`.

Comment: @Samuel please put the if body inside block brackets: `{ std::cout << test.id() << " " << test.result() << std::endl; } `

Comment: I don't think `#pragma omp atomic` does work here, you need `#pragma omp critical`

Comment: As the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106992/parallelize-output-using-openmp) I pointed out says, use `#pragma omp critical`.